# SQL Case When statement to count rows on multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle12c

I am trying to write a query which checks whether multiple tables have been populated, so I have to check multiple tables, in case that only one of them has 0 records then I have to return 'No' in output, otherwise if all of those tables have more than 0 (i.e 1,2,3... records) it should return 'YES'.

I have already tried using:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LorikSkema.TABLE1)  > 0 THEN 'YES'
    ELSE 'NO'
    END FROM DUAL;
```

This seems to work for only one table, but I'm having trouble finding a suitable query for multiple tables based on this logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AND` to add the checks for the other tables. But I think using `EXISTS` could be faster than `count(*)`.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM table1)
              AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM table2)
              ...
              AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM tablen) THEN
           'YES'
         ELSE
           'NO'
       END
       FROM dual;
```

Comment: just noticed that your CASE statement needs a closing END.  I tried to edit it, but the change doesn't meet the minimum character limit.